# What are these little horizontal lines coming off my button and how do I get rid of them

Tags: button, line

The join button has two horizontal lines coming off of it. I think it has something to do with the link element because I removed it and one line went away, but no both. I'm not sure what to do because I think I coded the other buttons the exact same way.

I am very new, so I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I can't quite figure it out[image: buttons page]

```
<style>
  .subscribe-button {
    background-color:rgb(206, 53, 53);
    color:white;
    border:none;
    height:42px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:2px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin-right:8px;
}
</style>

<style>
  .join-button {
    background-color:white;
    color:rgb(94, 122, 236);
    height:42px;
    width:66px;
    border-color:rgb(41, 118, 211);
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
</style>

<style>
  .tweet-button{
    background-color:rgb(29,155,240);
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    height:36px;
    width:70px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin-left:8px; 
  }
</style>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" Target="_blank">
  <button class="subscribe-button"
    >SUBSCRIBE
  </button>
</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
  <button class="join-button">
    JOIN
  </button>
</a>

<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
<button class="tweet-button">
  Tweet
</button>
</a>
```